# Grouping up elements from a list in Python 2.7

Tags: python, arrays, list, python-2.7, count

Ok, I got a huge text. I extract matches with regex (omitted here because it doesn't matter and I'm bad at this so you don't see how ugly my regex is :) ) and count them. Then, for readability, I split the elements and print them in the fashion I need:

```
import re
f = re.findall(r"(...)", PF)
a = [[y,f.count(y)] for y in set(f)]
(' '.join(map(str, j)) for j in w)
for element in w:
    print element
```

result is something like

```
['202', 1]
['213', 2]
['210', 2]
['211', 2]
['208', 2]
['304', 1]
['107', 2]
['133', 1]
['132', 1]
['131', 2]
```

What I need is to group up the elements, so that I get an output like

```
A ['133', 1]
  ['132', 1]
  ['131', 2]
B ['202', 1]
  ['213', 2]
C ['304', 1]
  ['107', 2]
  ['210', 2]
  ['211', 2]
  ['208', 2]
```

Note that:

- in the final result I will need 5 groups (A, B, C, D, E)
- the elements can vary, for example tomorrow 131 might not be present but I might have 232 that goes in group A and the number of elements is different every day
- it would be perfect, but not mandatory, if the elements in each group would be sorted numerically.
- Might sound obvious but I'll make it clear anyway, I know exactly which elements need to go in which group. If it is of any help, group *A can contain (102, 103), B(104,105,106,201,202,203), C(204,205,206,301,302,303,304), D(107,108,109,110,208,209,210,211,213,305,306,307), E(131,132,133,231,232)*.

The script needs to take the results that are present that day, compare them to the list above, and sort into the relative groups.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Looks very much like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39300055/1391444 any thing to edit from there? Or do I misunderstand?

Comment: For my understanding, if A, B... are not in the list, what is the grouping done by?

Comment: I'm looking into itertools groupby, that might do the trick, thanks. If I cannot figure it out I'll comment again :D

Editing the OP for clarity.

Comment: Thanks! Anyway `groupby()` is the tool to use I think.

Comment: What is `(' '.join(map(str, j)) for j in w)` supposed to do? You just create a generator and immediately discard it.

Comment: How comes the letters in your example output do not match the groups from your last bullet point? The three elements in A should actually be in E, C should be D, and B C. Also, is there any significance to the second number in the pairs?

Comment: You're right about the generator, it is a leftover piece of code from former tries. It does nothing at the moment. As regards the groups, the last bullet point is the actual result, all the others are just examples. @tobias_k

Answer (score 0):

You can set up a hash that maps elements to groups.  You can then transform each array item from [element,count] to (group,element,count) *(using a tuple to make it more easily sortable and such)*.  Sort that array, then use a loop or `reduce` to transform that into your final output.

```
mapElementsToGroups = {'131': 'A', '202': 'B', '304': 'C', …}

elementsFoundByGroup = {}
for (group, element, count) in sorted(
            [(mapElementsToGroups[item[0]], item[1], item[2])
                for item in a]
        ):
    elementsFoundByGroup[group] = elementsFoundByGroup.get(group, []) + [(element, count)]
```

You now have a dictionary mapping each group name found to the list of elements and counts found within that group.  The quick print is:

```
print [
            group + " " +
            elements.join("\n " + " "*len(group))
                for (group,elements) in sorted(elementsFoundByGroup.items())
        ].join("\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

One (probably not most elegant) solution would be to define a dictionary with the mappings and then lookup the name of the group to which the element belongs to.

```
elements = { "133": "A", "132": "A", 
             "202": "B", 
              ... }
```

The elements can then be added to a new dictionary with group names as keys:

```
groups = {"A":[], "B": [], ...}
for element, count in a:
    group = elements[element]
    groups[group].append( (element, count) )

for group in groups:
    groups[group].sort()                   # sort by element
    for element, count in groups[group]:
        print "%s %s %s" % (group, element, count)
```